# antlr 4 listeners stop in two places - weird

Tags: antlr4

I am parsing a SQL like language.

I want to parse full SQL sentence like : SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE and also a simple expr line which can be a function, where clause, expr and arithmethics.

this is the important parts of the grammar:

```
// main rule
parse : (statments)* EOF;


// All optional statements
statments : select_statement
        |   virtual_column_statement
;

    select_statement :  
        SELECT  select_item ( ',' select_item )* 
        FROM    from_cluase  ( ',' from_cluase )*
        (WHERE  where_clause )?
        ( GROUP BY group_by_item (',' group_by_item)* )?
        ( HAVING having_condition (AND having_condition)* )?
        ( ORDER BY order_clause (',' order_clause)* )?
        ( LIMIT limit_clause)? 
        | '(' select_statement ')'

   virtual_column_statement:    
            virtual_column_expression 
;

virtual_column_expression :
            expr
        |   where_clause
        |   function
        |   virtual_column_expression arithmetichOp=('*'|'/'|'+'|'-'|'%') virtual_column_expression
        |   '(' virtual_column_expression ')'
;
```

virtual_columns works great.

Select queries works too but after it finishes, it goes to virtual_column_statement too.

I want it to choose one.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**
After some research I found out antlr takes my query and seperate it to two different parts.

How can I fix this?

Thanks,
id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'virtual_column_statement' appears to be part of the 'select_statement'.  I expect that you are missing a ';' between the two rules.

Most of your 'select_statement' clauses are optional, so after matching the select and from clauses, if Antlr thinks that the balance of the input is better matched as a 'virtual_column_statement', then it will take that path.

Your choices are:

1) make your select_statement comprehensive and at least as general as your 'virtual_column_statement';

2) require a keyword at the beginning of the 'virtual_column_statement' to prevent Antlr from considering it as a partial alternate;

3) put the 'virtual_column_statement' in a separate parser grammar and don't send it any select input text.

Comment: Thanks, I added ';' at the end of each statements